# Android and ROS Communication over USB instead of Wifi

Tags: navigation, odometry, gps, wifi, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in running Android devices as IMUs, GPS sources, or even complete Odometry sources.  I once implemented this for IMUs a long time ago over the wifi, but there was some considerable delay and wifi's ability to drop out for a bit.  If this were to work well in most cases, data would have to be sent with minimal delay: thus USB.

So at this point, I know that rosjava wouldn't really be the mode of communication (yet?), since I'd be using serial, but does anyone know if Android can communicate via serial on its USB port?

I guess this would also ensure the android device stays charged.  :P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10235/android-and-ros-communication-over-usb-instead-of-wifi/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-06-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least with the Android Honeycomb tablets, turning on USB tethering will automatically mount the tablet as a network device.  This is how we run tablets tethered to netbooks for demos.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-06-15**:
Sorry Damon!  This is easier for my needs.  I confirmed that this works on Gingerbread (I have 2.3.4).  One more question: does anyone know how to hop across the networks.  Example: My usb tether is listed as 192.168.42.n, but the wifi clients are in 192.168.43.n.  Can I talk between them?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is now possible by using the [Open Accessory API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). You can get a serial channel to something like an Arduino over USB. You'll need a relatively recent Android device to make it work.

You could also check out the [IOIO](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10585) if you need to do this on an Android device that is pre 2.3.4.

In principle, you could do the same thing to open a serial channel to a laptop and then use the Android device as a wired IMU.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-06-13**:
Thanks, Damon!  I'll look into this.  I may have bought my Nexus S exactly for this purpose. :-P